# Performing an INNER JOIN across 2 tables with COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I'm stuck on an SQL query and I'm hoping you guys can help me out.

I have 2 tables:

```
EVENTS
event_id (PK)
event_name

ORDERS
order_id (PK)
event_id (FK)
```

and I'm trying to perform the following query on those tables:

```
SELECT
    e.event_id,
    e.name,
    COUNT(o.event_id) AS booked     
FROM
    events AS e
INNER JOIN
    orders AS o
ON
    e.event_id = o.event_id
WHERE
    e.event_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

The problem is that the result I'm getting is:

```
+----------+------+--------+
| event_id | name | booked |
+----------+------+--------+
|     NULL | NULL |      0 |
+----------+------+--------+
```

But when I run 3 separate queries with:

```
WHERE e.event_id IN (1)

WHERE e.event_id IN (2)

WHERE e.event_id IN (3)
```

I get the results I want:

```
+----------+-------+--------+
| event_id | name  | booked |
+----------+-------+--------+
|       1  | Test1 |      0 |
+----------+-------+--------+

+----------+-------+--------+
| event_id | name  | booked |
+----------+-------+--------+
|       2  | Test2 |      0 |
+----------+-------+--------+

+----------+-------+--------+
| event_id | name  | booked |
+----------+-------+--------+
|       3  | Test3 |      0 |
+----------+-------+--------+
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to use only one query and get:

```
+----------+-------+--------+
| event_id | name  | booked |
+----------+-------+--------+
|       1  | Test1 |      0 |
+----------+-------+--------+
|       2  | Test2 |      0 |
+----------+-------+--------+
|       3  | Test3 |      0 |
+----------+-------+--------+
```

Please help.

UPDATE:
When I run:

```
SELECT
    e.event_id,
    e.name,
    COUNT(o.event_id) AS booked     
FROM
    events AS e
LEFT JOIN
    orders AS o
ON
    e.event_id = o.event_id
WHERE
    e.event_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

I get only:

```
+----------+-------+--------+
| event_id | name  | booked |
+----------+-------+--------+
|       1  | Test1 |      0 |
+----------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` and don't forget to use `GROUP BY` clause since you are using *aggregate function* `COUNT()`.

```
SELECT  e.event_id,
        e.name,
        COUNT(o.event_id) AS booked     
FROM    events AS e
        LEFT JOIN orders AS o
            ON e.event_id = o.event_id
WHERE   e.event_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP   BY e.event_id, e.name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/814a3/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Both answers were correct but you were first :)

Answer (score 1):

Using left join with a if condition could do it

```
SELECT
  e.event_id,
  e.name,
  SUM(IF(o.event_id IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS booked
FROM events AS e
  LEFT JOIN orders AS o
    ON e.event_id = o.event_id
WHERE e.event_id IN(1, 2, 3)
GROUP   BY e.event_id, e.name
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/814a3/3)

Or you could do it like this too

```
SELECT
  e.event_id,
  e.name,
  COUNT(o.event_id) AS booked
FROM events AS e
  LEFT JOIN orders AS o
    ON e.event_id = o.event_id
WHERE e.event_id IN(1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY e.event_id, e.name
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/814a3/4)

Comment: why use additional condition when `COUNT` will suffice? `:D`